# Não estou conseguindo desenvolver meu código

Tags: javascript

Enunciado:

> Loop com Array - Saldo negativo
>
> Uma empresa mandou uma lista contendo os números mensais de tudo o que ela faturou, e nosso trabalho é ajudá-los a criar um relatório que exiba em quantos meses eles tiveram o saldo negativo.
>
> ```
> var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]
> ```
>
> Com base no array acima, que está disponível no código, faça um loop que verifique quantos meses tiveram valores negativos e armazene a contagem uma variável chamada `totalNegativos` que também está disponível no código.
>
> Utilize `.length` para trazer o tamanho do array.

Meu código até agora ficou assim:

```
var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]
var totalNegativos = 3

for (let i = 0; i < totalNegativos.length; i++) {
  if (totalNegativos[i] == busca) {
    console.log(" " + listaDeGanhos[i])
  }
}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=listaDeGanhos) perguntas, talvez elas te ajudem.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você precisa entender melhor a questão.

Qual o sentido do seu código??? Vamos lá::

```
var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]  // Aqui você tem a variável que carrega os valores. Então é dela que vc deve verificar a quantidade de saldos negativos.
var totalNegativos = 3 // o que tem essa variável????? Qual o sentido dela?????

for(let i=0; i < totalNegativos.length; i++){ // porque seu for só vai até 3, se o vetor com os valores é maior?

      if(totalNegativos[i] == busca){ // busca o que? essa variavel busca nem existe no contexto.

console.log(" " + listaDeGanhos[i])

}
```

Segue o código correto:

```js
console.log(calcularTotalNegativos());  // em javaScript vc começa chamando a função e vai imprimir o valor que estiver no retorno dela.

function calcularTotalNegativos(){
  var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40];
  var totalNegativos = 0; // essa variável vai guardar a quantidade de negativo

      for(let i=0; i < listaDeGanhos.length; i++){ // o for irá rodar até o tamanho do valor que estiver no vetor de valores.
        if(listaDeGanhos[i] < 0){ // algo negativo, se condiz ser menor que zero. Então compara os valores do vetor para ver se são menores que zero.
          totalNegativos++; // se for menor que zero, então soma a variável que irá guardar o número de negativos.
        }
      }
      return(totalNegativos); // retorna esse número ao fim da execução do for.
}
```

Procure estudar mais lógica.

Answer (score 1):

Esse exercício pode ser feito de diversas maneiras e vou te mostrar algumas delas, começando pela a que você está tentando resolver:

1. O primeiro passo é você definir numa variável sua `listaDeGanhos` e um array vazio de `saldoNegativo`.
2. Então você itera a `listaDeGanhos` utilizando o `for` e para cada item desta lista, você faz a verificação se o valor é menor ou igual a 0, caso seja, você irá armazena-lo no array `saldoNegativo`, utilizando o `push()`.
3. Depois é só chamar a variável `saldoNegativo`, que já conterá todos os meses que o saldo foram negativo.

```js
// declarar variáveis
var listaDeGanhos =  [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]
var saldoNegativo = [];
    
   // itera o array listaDeGanhos
for(i = 0; i < listaDeGanhos.length; i++ ){
  // verifica se o valor é igual ou menor que zero
  if( listaDeGanhos[i] <= 0){
    // adiciona o item no array de saldoNegativo
    saldoNegativo.push(listaDeGanhos[i]);
  }
}

// printa o valor de saldoNegativo
 console.log(saldoNegativo)

// printa a quantidade de itens em saldoNegativo
 console.log(saldoNegativo.length)
```

Outra forma de fazer é utilizando o **filter** do javascript, que torna o código muito mais simples, fazendo basicamente a mesma coisa que fizemos no trecho anterior.

1. A diferença aqui é que utilizei `let` ao invés de `var` para declarar a variávei `listaDeGanhos`, porque `var` se tornou obsoleto para declarar variáveis, mesmo que ainda seja muito utilizado. Também removi a declaração de `saldoNegativo` e passei para a próxima linha, onde ele já recebe o retorno do próprio método `filter`
2. Como o nome já diz, o filter() irá filtrar os elementos dentro de `listaDeGanhos` de acordo a condição que definirmos (no caso, todo item cujo valor for igual ou menor a 0)
3. O restante do código se mantém intocavél, apenas printando o resultado dentro de 'saldoNegativo'

```js
let listaDeGanhos =  [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40]

let saldoNegativo = listaDeGanhos.filter((item) => {
    return item <= 0
})

// printa o valor de saldoNegativo
console.log(saldoNegativo)

// printa o número de itens armazenados em saldoNegativo
console.log(saldoNegativo.length)
```

Espero ter ajudado (=

Answer (score 0):

Você deve somar a quantidade de meses, isto é, as posições do array. Ao colocar "+ listadeganhos[i]" você está somando o valor do conteúdo e não a posição.

```
var listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, -1, 40];
var totalNegativos = 0;

//seu loop aqui:
for (var i= 0 ; i < listaDeGanhos.length ; i++) {

    if (listaDeGanhos[i] < 0) {
        totalNegativos += 1; // Para acumular na variável os meses que são negativos.
    }   
}

console.log(totalNegativos)
```